# Difference between using ++ and +1 when use iterator

Tags: c++

We all know if we want to increase iterator we can use operator "++" or use "+1". Is there have difference betwen `++` and `+1`?

Now, I run this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int Str(string &s, string::iterator it)
{
    if(it == s.end())
        return 0;
    else 
    { 
        return (1 + Str(s,it++)); // Wrong line of code.When using "it + 1" 
                                  //programme could get right result but 
                                  //when using "it++" programme could not
                                  // get right result
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string s;
    cout << "enter: ";
    cin >> s;

    string::iterator it = s.begin();
    int i = Str(s,it);
    cout << "str= " << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use iterator as a function parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that in

```
return (1 + Str(s, it++));
```

you are using the postfix increment operator, which performs the increment but returns the iterator in its state before the increment. You can change this to

```
return (1 + Str(s, ++it));
```

which should yield the desired result. Note that `it + 1` works for [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) only. It does the same in your case, but you could try to enforce as little constraints as possible for the iterators in use, e.g., when you change your container to one that works with [bidirectional iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), it would be desirable that your code still works. I'd hence recommend going with `++it`.

Note that there is also the function template [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), which increments the given iterator. It is also quite readable to go with

```
return (1 + Str(s, std::next(it));
```

Comment: One more question: why recursive function must use "&s" ? The recursive function did not change "s" at all.Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the question. Do you mean the function signature `int Str(string &s, string::iterator it)` and why the first argument is `string& s` instead of `string s`?

Comment: Yes,that's what I want to ask.

Comment: The function parameter `string &s` is passed by reference, while `string s` would create a copy upon each function call. When the argument is mutated inside the function, this affects the argument in the calling scope only in the first case.

Answer (score 5):

Not all iterators can do `+1`. Only random access iterators can do this. All iterators can do `++` though. But there are two versions of `++`.

Then your mistake is that `i++` computes `i+1` but returns the previous value. What you want is `++i`, returning the new incremented iterator.